# Memory error in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, categorical-data

I am trying to build this converter for one of my personal project using numpy and getting the Memory error. I am new to python. This works fine for small data but breaks when i give 5MB of data as input(attached the data). Here is the code. Could experts point out where the memory is blowing up here? Link to data can be found [here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00222/)

```
import numpy as np
import gc as gc

"""
USAGE: convert(data,cols)
        data - numpy array of data
        cols - tuple of columns to process. These columns should be categorical columns. 
        IMP: Indexing of colum in data starts with 0. Ypou cant index last column.

        Ex: you want to index second col here, then

        data
        a b c
        a b c
        x y z

        cols=(1,)

        if you want to index 1st and second, then

        cols=(0,1)

        All 3

        cols=(0,1,2)

        You can also skip numeric column, which you dont want to encode, like

        cols=(0,2) will skip 1 col

"""

def lookupBuilder(strArray):
    a=np.arange(len(strArray))+1
    lookups={k:v for (k,v) in zip(strArray,a)}
    return lookups

def convert(data,cols):    

    for ix,i in  enumerate(cols):
        col=data[:,i:i+1]
        lookup_data=lookupBuilder(np.unique(col))

        for idx,value in enumerate(col):
            col[idx]=lookup_data[value[0]]

        np.delete(data,i,1)
        gc.collect()
        np.insert(data,i,col,axis=1)  

    return data


if __name__=="__main__":    
    pass
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\MLDatabases\python_scripts\MLP.py", line 230, in <module>
  data=cc.convert(data,(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,13,19)) 
File "C:\MLDatabases\python_scripts\categorical_converter.py", line 49, in convert 
  np.insert(data,i,col,axis=1) 
File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4906, in insert 
  new = empty(newshape, arr.dtype, arrorder) 
MemoryError
```

Comment: Error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MLDatabases\python_scripts\MLP.py", line 230, in <module>
    data=cc.convert(data,(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,13,19))
  File "C:\MLDatabases\python_scripts\categorical_converter.py", line 49, in convert
    np.insert(data,i,col,axis=1)  
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4906, in insert
    new = empty(newshape, arr.dtype, arrorder)
MemoryError

Comment: we need a little more detail, like how you use it, and the goal, and is better with a working example... also it looks to me like maybe [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) might be more appropriate for this job

Comment: I'm surprised it works even for small data.  `np.delete` and `np.insert` do not operate in-place.  But the error arises when `insert` tries to crate a new array where it can place `data` and the new `col` values.  If your data gets too big, memory errors are inevitable.

Comment: @hpaulj can you please explain what you mean by do not operate in-place. I have 4GB RAM and trying to manipulate 5MB of data, so i dont think its really availability of memory which is causing this error.

Comment: `data1 = np.delete(data,i,1)` creates a new array.  It does not change the `data` array you give it as an argument.  Similarly with `np.insert`.  These are not methods like `alist.append(...)`.  These are functions.

Comment: @hpaulj - Can you please try below. It works 

a=np.array(np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)%3,dtype=np.str)
np.place(a,np.array(a,dtype=np.int)>-1,['a','b','c'])
convert(a,(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))